# Question about Riemann Integration and the indicator function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose $\chi_S$ is integrable on $Q$  for some rectangle $Q$ such that $S \subseteq Q $.  Let $\epsilon > 0 $ be given, I want to ask how can I show that there exist rectangles $R_1,R_2,...,R_k,...,R_n$ $(0 < k < n )$ such that $\bigcup_{i=1}^k R_i \subseteq S \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n R_i $ and $\sum_{i=k+1}^n Vol(R_i) < \epsilon $.

Intuitively this makes sense, but I am struggling a lot in trying to show it rigorously. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how we extend the Riemann integration to higher dimensional spaces? can you give me some reference plz?

Comment: @GA316: You're asking in the wrong place: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: @user2357112 oh,is it?  sorry, I dont know that ! ! !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic function $\chi_S$ being Riemann integrable means precisely that for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a partition of $Q$ into finitely many "almost disjoint" closed boxes $R_k$ such that
$$U(\chi_S)-L(\chi_S)=\sum_k\bigl(\sup_{x\in R_k}\chi_S(x)-\inf_{x\in R_k}\chi_S(x)\bigr){\rm vol}(R_k)<\epsilon$$
for this partition. Put
$$J:=\{k\>|\> R_k\subset S\},\qquad J':=\{k\>|\>R_k\cap S\ne\emptyset\}\ .$$
Then
$$\bigcup_{k\in J}R_k\subset S\subset\bigcup_{k\in J'} R_k\ .$$
As $\chi_S(x)\equiv1$ on all $R_k$ with $k\in J$, and $\chi_S(x)\equiv0$ on all $R_k$ with $k\notin J'$ it follows that
$$\sum_{k\in J'\setminus J}{\rm vol}(R_k)=U(\chi_S)-L(\chi_S)<\epsilon\ .$$

Comment: how we extend the Riemann integration to higher dimensional spaces? can you give me some reference plz?

Comment: @GA316: See here: http://www.math.ethz.ch/~blatter/Analysis_13.pdf , the first few pages (in German).

Comment: Thank you sir. One question, why $\sum_{k \in J' \setminus J} Vol(R_k) < \epsilon $? I found that $L( \chi_S ) = 0 $. Is this correct ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems not true in general. In $\mathbb{R}^2$, Consider $S$ as the set of all $(x,y)$ in $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ such that atleast one of $x$ or $y$ is irrational and $Q$ to be any rectangle containing $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ . These $S$ and $Q$ satisfies the given condition and $S$ contains no rectangle at all.

Comment: But $\chi_S$ is not Riemann integrable (note *Riemann Integration* in the title).

Comment: @HowAboutaNiceBigCupof oh. sorry. I thought it is Labesgue integration.

Comment: @HowAboutaNiceBigCupof how we extend the Riemann integration higher dimensional spaces? can you give me some reference plz?